# addTarger to textfield on value changed is no called

Tags: ios

I have a textField and I want to be notified on each character entered, so I add target with `.valueChanged`. But it never called.

Target

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldTextDidChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Method

```
func textFieldTextDidChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return }
    delegate?.searchBarDidEnter(text: text)
}
```

I seted up breakpoint on method and it never enters inside

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to use event `editingChanged` not `valueChanged`.

```
 textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldTextDidChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```